# Compiler error : Cannot use a method returning javax.xml.transform.Result as an Handler in routes in play framework

Tags: java, playframework, routes, playframework-2.2

**controllers->Students.java**

```
public class Students extends Controller { 

        /* Create a new student form */

        public static Result create(){
            Form<Student> studentform = form(Student.class);
            return ok(createstudentform.render(studentform));
        }
        public static Result save(){
            Form<Student> studentform = form(Student.class).bindFromRequest();
            if(studentform.hasErrors()){
                return badRequest(createstudentform.render(studentform));
            }
            studentform.get.save();
            flash("success", "Student" + studentform.get().usn + "has been created");
            return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
        }
}
```

Routes:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

# Add a student

GET     /students/new              controllers.Students.create()
POST    /students                  controllers.Students.save()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Compilation error:

```
Cannot use a method returning javax.xml.transform.Result as an Handle
```

Comment: Which line has the compilation error?  What are your imports?

Comment: GET /students/new controllers.Students.create() had the compilation error. Got that error corrected somehow. Thankyou

Comment: What are your imports?